# after GET https://some.com/some prisma.some.findMany() crashed with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: axios, nestjs, prisma, node-fetch

```
if
    // any
    prisma.some.findMany() // all ok

if
    // any
    const some = await axios.get('https://some.com/some') // or nestjs/axios or node-fetch
    console.log(some)
    // ...
    console.log('before')
    prisma.some.findMany()
    console.log('after')

logs in test:
{/*some*/}
before
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

[image]

I use:

- windows 10
- "prisma": "4.8.0",
- "@prisma/client": "4.8.0",
- "@nestjs/core": "9.0.0",
- "@nestjs/axios": "1.0.1",
- "axios": "^1.3.3",
- "node-fetch": "2",
- "typescript": "4.7.4"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for posting your code, but what are we supposed to do with it? Please read [ask] and [edit] the question with some text on what this code is supposed to do, what it currently does (fail, I presume) and preferably what you've tried to solve this already. This would make it clearer to us what you're attempting to achieve and thus easier to help you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how do you get this error?